# Emacs, Auto Complete Mode, CSS, pain. (illustrated!)

Tags: css, emacs, autocomplete

I've got [Auto Complete Mode](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) installed for Emacs.

**First:** When I'm typing declarations I get the normal auto-complete behavior:

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

So I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete — no problem. But then I hit <kbd>;</kbd>:

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

It instantly tries to complete something! And I can't hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> because that'll accept the erroneous completion!

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

So I have to hit <kbd>C-j</kbd>. What a pain.

**Second:** Once I'm done with a declaration, I type <kbd>}</kbd>:

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

...but it doesn't get indented properly unless I type <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

What gives?

*Update, settings:*

I'm using Emacs 23. My `css-electric-keys` are `}` and `;`. My Auto Complete configuration is as follows:

```
(ac-config-default)
(setq ac-auto-start t)
(setq ac-delay 0.1)
(setq ac-auto-show-menu nil)
(setq ac-show-menu-immediately-on-auto-complete t)
(setq ac-trigger-key nil)
```

Comment: Really? A vote to close? I can't ask Emacs questions on SO anymore? :(

Comment: Close vote offset by my +1 for showing me that this thing exists.

Comment: The question is "what gives?"  Despite all the graphics and the nice formatting, "what gives?" doesn't seem to be much of a question.  If I try to interpret your questions, you seem to be asking about both auto-complete and indentation.  One question per post, please.

Comment: @abelenky, If I could vote down your stuffy comment, I would.  Why are you insisting that he rephrase his question in complete, proper english? Maybe you are a Turing machine...  He wants to know how to make it work better. if you don't have the answer, step back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a few suggestions:

1. `(setq ac-auto-start t)` starts autocomplete automatically. If you change that to `(setq ac-auto-start 1)` (or 2 or 3) then it will only start after that many characters have been typed. This might not solve your problem though if after you type the `;`, it considers the entire preceding word as part of the current auto-complete search.
2. Maybe the problem is that it isn't recognizing the semicolon as a delimiting character (like whitespace), so it thinks you're still adding to the last word. Perhaps adding the semicolon string to ac-ignores would do the trick? (Not sure what the syntax for that would be)
3. Maybe you can prevent auto-completion via the enter key by adding: `(define-key ac-complete-mode-map "\t" 'ac-complete)` and `(define-key ac-complete-mode-map "\r" nil)`. I'm not sure how this will interact with DWIM though (enabled by default).
4. Try adding semicolon as an auto-complete key?

My .emacs knowledge on a scale of 0 to 10 is like a 1.5, but maybe this will jog some better ideas.

Comment: I think removing the enter key from the keymap is the best solution.  It routinely gets in the way when you really *did* want the shortened version of something longer.  TAB actually already works pretty well as you'd expect even without the first snippet.

Comment: Sweet! `(define-key ac-complete-mode-map "\r" nil)` works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Old stuff I know, but try the following:

```
(add-hook 'css-mode-hook       
  (lambda ()
     (make-local-variable 'ac-ignores)
     (add-to-list 'ac-ignores ";")))
```

From [the manual](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Stop_completion_automatically_after_inserting_specific_words)

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful, fixed a problem that really irritated me! :)